# Get posts in a Specifc Category from a Another Site in Wordpress Multisite Network

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

- I am using this code to pull posts from a specific category from another site on a Wordpress multisite install. But it is outputting all the posts and not filtering by the specified category. Any ideas what I am missing? The category is being ignored after the switch, the numberposts and order is honored. Thanks for any help.

```
global $switched;
switch_to_blog(4); //switched to 4

// Get latest Post
$latest_posts = get_posts('category=-28&numberposts=6&orderby=post_name&order=DSC');
$cnt =0;?> 
    <?php foreach($latest_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>

            <?php 
            
                // do something
               echo('<div style="position:relative;padding:20px;margin-bottom:20px;background:rgb(249, 249, 249) url(https://cra.org/crn/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2016/01/cerp-back-faint.png) no-repeat right bottom;
         border-top: 2px solid #1b806e;
        ">');
            
            echo('<h4 style="font-size:16px;margin:5px 0 5px 0;"><a style="color:#1b806e!important;text-decoration:none" href="');
            the_permalink();
            echo('" title="');
            the_title_attribute();
            echo('">');
            the_title();
            echo('</a></h4>');
            if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'byline', true) ) {
            echo ('<em>By ');
            echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'byline', true);
            echo ('</em>');
            }
            if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
             $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
             echo '<a href="'; the_permalink(); echo '" title="'; the_title_attribute(); echo '">';
             echo '<img style="padding:1em" align="right" width="100" src="' . $image[0] . '">';
             echo '</a>';
            }
            the_excerpt();
                // read more button
                echo '<small><a style="font-size: 10px !important;padding: 6px 10px;margin: 0 1px 1px 0;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;border-color: #eee;text-decoration: none;color: #f9f9f9;background: #75accb;text-transform: uppercase;border-radius: 20px;" href="';
                the_permalink();
                echo '" title="';
                the_title_attribute();
                echo '">Read More</a></small>';
                
                                                                
        ?>                                          
        
        </div>


     <?php endforeach ; ?>

<?php restore_current_blog(); //switched back to main site ?>
```

Comment: The category is `-28`? That seems weird, are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Yes - that is what the syntax is.

Comment: Wow, I've contributed to WordPress core several times and I never knew that you could negate a category by doing that! Learn something new every day! So, just to be clear, when you say "from a specific category" you mean you are wanting to exclude that category, right? Also, these are native WordPress posts (not CPTs) using the native category taxonomy, right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. -28 does remove that specific category and shows the rest, when I use the code on the blog that the posts and category is native to. IE. I use the same code in a template on blog id 4. If I use that code on blog id 3, it returns no results. the -28 works though. I am trying to pull that specific category with ID = 28 (native post type and category); from Blog 3 into Blog 4.